# Form field value is not sent to PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Here is my entire(most of it) script for new_posts.php 
Update query not working but instead its adding a new post to the database.

```
 if(isset($_POST['add_post'])) {

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['title']);
$author = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['author']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['category']);
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['body']);
$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['keywords']);

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);
  $query = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title',author='$author',category='$category',body='$body',keywords='$keywords' WHERE id='$id'";
}else{
  $d = getDate();
  $date = "$d[month] $d[mday], $d[year]";

  $query = "INSERT INTO posts (title,author,category,body,keywords,date) VALUES('$title','$author','$category','$body','$keywords','$date')";
}
$db->query($query);
}

if(isset($_GET['post'])) {
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['post']);
  $p = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'");
  $p = $p->fetch_assoc();
}

$cats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");

?>
```

This is some of the HTML section.

```
    <h1 class="page-header">Add New Post</h1>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <form method="post">
        <?php if(isset($p)) {
          echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='$id'/>";
        } ?>
```

Comment: Is id in GET or POST? You're checking it's set in POST but then escaping it in GET

Comment: updated my question for you to see more code

Answer (score 1):

If a new record is being inserted then your `UPDATE` query isn't running at all, your `INSERT` query is.  So this check is `false`:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
```

Looking at what you expect would supply `$_POST['id']`:

```
"<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='$id'/>"
```

Unless the string value `id` is in the `$id` variable, this won't be called `id` at all.  It seems that the name for this element is the number of your database `id`.

Don't use the *variable* `$id` as the name, use the literal string `id` since that's what the server-side code expects:

```
"<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"
```

Comment: I have updated the question for you to see more of the code. Unfortunately change name from ..... name='$id' to name='id'.....did not work.

Comment: @GrahamMiller: In what specific way does it now fail?  Note that you're also trying to reference *both* `$_POST['id']` and `$_GET['id']`.  Based on the `<form>` tag you're now showing us, I'd only expect `$_POST['id']` to contain a value.  You can debug to confirm your SQL query.

Comment: it fails in not updating to the database but instead it inserts new records to the database. I have created a blog CMS, the user can edit his/her posts. This is the user editing the post but instead of it being edited/updated it is creating a new blog post and keeping the old one.

Comment: @GrahamMiller: Then it's time for you to do some debugging.  When you attempt to update a record, what is the value of `$_POST['id']`?  What specific code blocks are executed?  (That is, do you go into the `if` or the `else` in question?)  What is the value of the SQL query you're executing?

Comment: if I var_dump($_POST['id']); then I get the id of the post that I am editing, which is correct then when I want to edit the post I need it to update the information of the post with that id which isn't happening but instead its skipping the if statement and doing the else. hope this helps?

Comment: @GrahamMiller: *"then when I want to edit the post"* - Is this happening on a separate step?  The specific order of operations taking place isn't clear from your description.  But if these are separate steps then what's true on one step is not necessarily true on the other.  It's not "skipping the if statement", the code is doing exactly what it's written to do.  If the condition is false then the condition is false.  Try creating a new complete minimal example of just the functionality you're debugging.  A small form, a small PHP handler for that form.  Does the problem exist there?